# EF Code First Lazy loading Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am using code first with EF6 but cannot seem to get lazy loading to work. Eager loading is working fine. I have the following classes:

```
public class Merchant : User
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<MerchantLocation> MerchantLocations { get; set; }
}

public class MerchantLocation : BaseEntity
{
    ...

    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }       
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    ...

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I test my lazy loading of the locations via the following code (which fails):

```
public void Test_Lazy_Loading() {
    using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
        var merchant = context.Users.OfType<Merchant>.First();
        merchant.MerchantLocations.ShouldNotBeNull(); // fails
    }
}
```

However eager loading works fine:

```
public void Test_Eager_Loading() {
    using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
        var merchant = context.Users.OfType<Merchant>.Include("MerchantLocations").First();
        merchant.MerchantLocations.ShouldNotBeNull(); // passes
    }
}
```

`MerchantLocations` is marked as `public virtual` so I'm not sure what the problem is. I have also added the following in my `DbContext` constructor:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

edit: I have also noticed that the `merchant` object being returned in the above tests is not an EF proxy. It is a plain `Merchant`. I suspect that this is causing the problem.

Comment: Not answering your question but its bad design to use a base entity class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553510.aspx

Comment: I'm guessing it might be because your using the OfType, how come you don't access the Merchants directly from the context but instead go through users

Comment: I see what the author is saying about a base entity class, but the default settings in EF actually map these properties into the derived tables rather than making a separate BaseEntity table, so performance isn't affected. I don't really think his conceptual argument is very strong; I need some change tracking info like DateAdded and DateUpdated, so a base class made this easier

Comment: @DanielPowell I'm guessing not using a base class has more to do with generated edmx files than for code-first mappings. If you're going code-first, this problem is easily avoided. The base class then allows you to use generics to potentially save thousands of lines of code that you would otherwise have to maintain.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I realized that the problem was that the Merchant class did not meet requirements for proxy generation. Specifically, I needed to add a protected parameterless constructor. I only had a private one.

Comment: i have public parameterless constructor but still doesn't work

Comment: I want to know would the constructor include all the attributes including the virtual attributes

Answer (score 5):

Another thing that can cause lazy loading to fail is **navigation properties that are not virtual**. That was not the case for OP, but this question is a top Google result so it may help some.

And yet another possible cause is a **mapped database column that doesn't exist**. I was surprised to see that break lazy loading rather than throw a database exception.